# How to display a login failure messagebox for App.Config connection string

Tags: vb.net, app-config

I use the following connection string and am able to log into SQL 2008 R2 Server.

```
My.Settings.Item("CustomerConnectionString") = "Data Source=FAROOK-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial 
Catalog= '" & Me.ComboBox1.Text & "'; uid = '" & Me.Login1.Text & "'; pwd = '" & 
Me.Password1.Text & "'"
```

How do I display a messagebox on login failure.

Thank you.

Comment: wrap in try/catch and catch the exception....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601497/test-sql-connection-without-throwing-exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use Try Catch Block. If connection fails use yor message box in catch block.

```
Dim sqlCnn As New SqlConnection
Dim connString as string = "Your Connection String"
Try
   sqlCnn = New SqlConnection(connString)
   sqlCnn.open()
Catch ex As SqlException
   MsgBox("Login Failed")

End Try
```

Comment: Correct...This was just to show the correct approach. Now it can be modified to make a more efficient code. :)

Comment: Geek, actually I am replacing the App.config connection string from code. This helps me not to add connection string on each and every form. This way I can easily use Tableadapters. My connection string works. On login success it opens form1, but on login failure too the form opens. The App.config file is absolutely safe, the connectionstring is hard coded.

Comment: Yes Farook you can pick up the connection string value once from app.config in a global variable and then use it as many times you want.

Comment: So what is the solution Geek? I can't "Try Catch". I want to verify the uid and pwd after the connstring is loaded. The string goes as My.Settings.Item(CustomerConnetionString) etc. this is the issue.

Comment: How do you verify uid and pwd? are you matching it with some entry? If  yes then what is the need of using a hard coded conn string. If you are checking the entries from textkbox then compare it before creating the conn string.

Comment: What I mean by hard coded is that the App.config consists on the server name, thus, instead of App.config doing the work I override the App.config connstring by hard coding my connstring, which is what I have mentioned in my thread. Here is the entire button1.click:

Comment: Your idea to compare a login/pwd textbox is a good idea. I think we can finish off if you could post a code snippet.

Comment: Private Sub LoginBtn1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles LoginBtn1.Click
        My.Settings.Item("CustomerConnectionString") = "Data Source=FAROOK-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog= '" & Me.ComboBox1.Text & "'; uid = '" & Me.Login1.Text & "'; pwd = '" & Me.Password1.Text & "'"
        Form1.Show()
        Me.Hide()
    End Sub

Comment: Before form1.show() check weather the credentials are valid or not by using the try catch block. If connection is successful then show the form or use the catch block to show the message that the credentials are not valid. I think this will help.

Comment: Dim con1 = New SqlConnection("Data Source=FAROOK-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog= '" & Me.ComboBox1.Text & "'; uid = '" & Me.Login1.Text & "'; pwd = '" & Me.Password1.Text & "'")

Comment: I am using two type of connection string one is to veryfity crediantals and the other is for global use. Both are connection strings but a loaded twice. Try/Catch is being used and error are thrown to msgbox. My worry is that 2 connstrings are used. We should be able to verify My.Settings... I am clocking off. Should you get any ideas pls post. I could send the code as an attachment if I know you e-mail address. Thanks/Regards

Comment: This is a very simple solution: Have one connection string use the same for verification as well as other db connections.

Comment: Geek, my code is running. I am using two connection strings. My problem is I am connecting to the Server twice. If I can validate My.Settings string then it would be good.

Comment: Geek: To sum it up could you post the code for My.Settings connection string.

Comment: I have posted the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8815022/how-to-use-try-catch-to-display-login-failure-for-app-config-connection-string/8818396#8818396